# Is the openjdk-r ppa trustworty?

Tags: java, ppa, openjdk

I've seen a ton of blogs saying Java 8 is now available to Ubuntu 12.04 & 14.04 through the ppa openjdk-r. My question is how trustworthy is this ppa? Is it run by people from openjdk or ubuntu or something, or is it just some random dude?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, it is trustworthy.

The PPA is run by Matthias Klose (Member of Ubuntu, Canonical Partner Developer, Gnome3 Team, Edubuntu developer, Xubuntu developer, ...) .

---

References :

[Matthias Klose Profile on lauchpad](https://launchpad.net/~doko)
[Debian's packages overview for Matthias Klose](https://qa.debian.org/developer.php?login=doko%40ubuntu.com)

Comment: trustworthy != secure; use java 7 update 95 at your own risk. openjdk-7 (7u95-2.6.4-3)

Answer (score 3):

I have used it in the past, but openjdk site does not refer to it (that I can tell). The administrator of that ppa group is a member of many other groups including "Canonical Partner Developers”. If Canonical trusts him than I don't see a problem. His name (according to his launchpad profile) is [Matthias Klose](https://launchpad.net/~doko).